Ideas for a function which generates a skewed random distribution plot
I am trying to figure out a function that can plot a curve similar to these ones:

The area under the curve is 1, since this is a density plot. However, it doesn't look like I can fit a gaussian to mimic this type of function. Any ideas on what type of function can do this?

Gaussian mixure model
